# Can between/3 not be recursive?

Tags: prolog, instantiation-error

I've seen the [Prolog Prologue](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue#between) definition of `between/3`:

```
between(Lower, Upper, Lower) :-
   Lower =< Upper.
between(Lower1, Upper, X) :-
   Lower1 < Upper,
   Lower2 is Lower1 + 1,
   between(Lower2, Upper, X).
```

I don't understand why it requires recursion. A logical definition of `between` could be:

```
between(Lower, Upper, Something):-
   Lower =< Upper,
   Lower =< Something,
   Something =< Upper.
```

I tried that on `gprolog` and it works, but only for simple queries:

```
| ?- between(0,5,1).

yes
```

For queries with variables I get:

```
| ?- between(0,5,X).
uncaught exception: error(instantiation_error, (=<)/2)
```

I don't really understand why.

I kind of figure Prolog needs some sort of reference number to unify variables against, but why the cryptic error on `(=<)/2`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is not that cryptic, once you know what *general purpose arithmetic* in Prolog does. In short, it is simply there to do non-logical, "calculate this and give me the answer" kind of arithmetic. Comparisons (so all the `</2`, `=</2`, `=:=/2`, etc) require that you have *arithmetic expressions* on both sides; `is/2` assumes that it has an arithmetic expression on the left side and a free variable on the right. So, you can do stuff like:

```
?- X is 3^1.3.
X = 4.171167510947728.

?- 1 =:= sin(pi/2).
true.
```

If you actually read the GNU-Prolog manual carefully enough, you should find, at the beginning of the [relevant section](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec97), the following two sentences:

> An arithmetic expression is a Prolog term built from numbers, variables, and functors (or operators) that represent arithmetic functions. When an expression is evaluated **each variable must be bound to a non-variable expression**.

(Emphasis mine)

Predicates like `between/3`, `plus/3`, or `succ/2` are examples of *special purpose integer arithmetic*. They have their uses. However, most of the uses for doing actual integer math have been superseded by CLPFD. For GNU-Prolog, you should [consult the documentation](http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec299), but for a short example, to emulate `between/3`, you could say:

```
?- fd_domain(X, 0, 2), fd_labeling(X).
X = 0 ? ;
X = 1 ? ;
X = 2
yes
```

You should notice that this is definitely **not** recursive (to answer the question in the title). Of course, we are all aware that at some level, there is recursion or iteration involved, in order to get these answers.